# How can I fetch XML Data from a file stored on my PC and populate a table in HTML using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, html-table

Please see my XML and HTML below:
All I want to do is generate a HTML table by using the data in my XML file.
(This XML file is in my C directory but in the same folder as the HTML file.)
(C:/Users/Admin/Documents/GameStats/main.html --> Being the main html file).
(C:/Users/Admin/Documents/GameStats/game.xml --> Being the XML file).

I will appreciate any help. I don't mind JAVASCRIPT, AJAX, JQUERY. 
I would really appreciate if you can tell me my mistake.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <GAME>
        <COUNTRY>
            <NAME>China</NAME>
            <PLAYERS>80,000</PLAYERS>
            <KILLS>35,060</KILLS>
        </COUNTRY>
        <COUNTRY>
            <NAME>Pakistan</NAME>
            <PLAYERS>234</PLAYERS>
            <KILLS>340</KILLS>
        </COUNTRY>
        <COUNTRY>
            <NAME>Indonesia</NAME>
            <PLAYERS>867</PLAYERS>
            <KILLS>546</KILLS>
        </COUNTRY>
    </GAME>
```

And this is the HTML Document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get Game Stats</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
//document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "/game.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Name</th><th>Players</th><th>Kills></th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY");

  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("PLAYERS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>"  +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("KILLS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I will appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Should be run on a webserver to work. On windows you might be able to use the `file://` protocol but if my memory serves me well I believe browser might need a flag enable in order to allow the file protocol. Probably easier to build a little nodejs webserver to support it.

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: I don't see anything when I click on the button. Nothing is generated.

Comment: I have tried running it on a server as well, same problem occurs.

Comment: @mrkn0007  when you say "I have tried running it on a server as well", what do you mean? Can you update your question to include what you tried?

Comment: also, check F12 console for errors.

Comment: Thank you guys, for all of your help. The solution mentioned below alongside Xampp server worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a couple of issues: You need a local test server to try out stuff like this unless you want to constantly upload files to a remote server to test them. There are LOTS of ways to set up local test servers (Python, PHP has a built-in test server, Virtual Machines, etc..) but with xampp you'll be up and running in about 5 min. It's free and you'll find videos or tutorials about setting it up, even though it's easy.

Second is loading XML, I use the following:

```
function loadXML() {
    var urlVar = ('myXML.xml'); // where your xml file lives
    var succVar = xmlLoaded; // what to do after it's loaded
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlVar,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: succVar
    });
}
function xmlLoaded(data) {
    var loadedXML = data;
    console.log('xml', $(loadedXML).find('game').html()); // display the content of <game> in your console window
}
```